# Offmargin numbering and others with titlesec

Tags: formatting, titlesec

Please help me to understand `titlesec` because my old head and my skill on understanding english and code seem cannot bear anymore. I have read the documentation and seem that I cannot understand how to be in tune with this.

So, I'm trying to make something like this.[image] Basically it's just a section without a title (means that merely just number here) that go off margin (the blue line is the margin of the text) marking each necessary paragraph. The paragraph always has no indentation if it's marked, indicating that it's the first paragraph of each text. It sorta like when you are going to give a numbering of original translation. Is it possible to do this with `titlesec` or is there another more efficient way to do this? Thank you.

Comment: Is that the only way you want to section the text or are there going to be 'normal' sections with titles anywhere or on any level in your document?

Comment: @moewe There are, and I plan to use this kind of thing only for `\subsection` and `\subsubsection`. Is it possible?